# this.file.listDir won't return folders under the externalRootDirectory on Android

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native, ionic5, cordova-plugin-file

I am trying to select directories of file:///storage/emulated/0/images/ with ionic-native/file but the Entry[] et return 0.
I tried different folders under **externalRootDirectory** but get the same 0 results. I think maybe the cordova-plugin-file issue with capacitor, ionic-native/file. Can anyone list the folders, files under Root?

I have 100+ files in images but the Entry[] et keep return 0 if I use this code.

```
let _app_EXT_Root_Dir = this.file.externalRootDirectory;
this.file.listDir(_app_EXT_Root_Dir,"images").then( et =>{
      console.log("List Dir: " + et.length); // --> always List Dir: 0
    });
```

I'm working with Ionic 5 - Capacitor 3 - Angular.
"@ionic-native/file": "^5.36.0" 
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution. The plugin works fine on Android 9 but not on Android 10.

In Android 10, you have to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your config `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<application 
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```